# How can I plot a CDF with columns from .csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, pythonplotter

I try to plot a CDF with data from my csv-file. I already found some code in web, but I don't get the point where I can say from which column in my csv I want the data in my CDF.
I want to use pandas since I use it for other plots.

The .csv looks like this:

RSRP,RSRQ,SINR
-89,-15,-8
-90,-12,9

The only code I have so far is the pointer to the data:

```
data_req = pd.read_table("C:\\Users\\A64842363\\Desktop\\PLOTS\\München_Taxi\\MY_Bahnhof_Bridge_800_1800_2600_Sample_PP.csv", sep=",")
```

I want to use column 'rsrp'.

How do I get a CDF from this? I'm a beginner in Python..

Comment: can u put ur code and ur data?

Comment: See above. I only have a pointer to my data so far.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to plot a column named "col_x" as your CDF. You can select that column with `your_pandas_df["col_x"]`. That will create a pointer to the column of type `pandas.Series`. You should be able to pass that to your plotting function.

Comment: Thank you so far. See above. I only have a pointer to my data so far